# Definition of the Derivative of a Function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I'm supposed to show $$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h} $$
I know I must use substitution at some point, but I don't think I can substitute $x - h$ for $x$. The definition I am using for $f^\prime(x)$ is $f^\prime(x) = \mbox{lim}_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $,but I also could use $f^\prime(a) = \mbox{lim}_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

Comment: Just replace $h$ by $-h$ and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

shouldn't the definition be $f^\prime(x) = \mbox{lim}_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ ?

Comment: I have edited the question so that the definition is correct.

Comment: In any case I don't understand what you are supposed to prove, what's $a$? I think you should check if this is actually ok

Answer (score 1):

Several things went wrong. First of all we have

$f'(a)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$,  if the limit exists.

I think that you have to show

$$f'(a)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{h}.$$

Hint: $\frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{h}=\frac{f(a-h)-f(a)}{-h}.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: This has clarified what I'm supposed to answer. I still don't see how I move from the first definition to what I am supposed to show. Do I substitute?

Comment: Hint number two: with $k=-h$ we have $\frac{f(a-h)-f(a)}{-h}=\frac{f(a+k)-f(a)}{k}$ and we have $h \to 0 \iff k\to 0$.